# Multiple labels for some emails

Tags: google-api, gmail-api

When we trash a mail after sending it, the UI displays it with only the "Trash" label. However, the API shows both "Sent" and "Trash"

```
{
 "id": "16169c0c3d212e74",
 "threadId": "16169c0c3d212e74",
 "labelIds": [
  "TRASH",
  "SENT"
 ],
 "snippet": "#Testing ",
 "historyId": "1893418",
 "internalDate": "1517897696000",
 "payload": {
  "partId": "",
  "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
  "filename": "",
  "headers": [
   {
    "name": "MIME-Version",
    "value": "1.0"
   },
   {
    "name": "Received",
    "value": "by xx.xx.xx.xx with HTTP; Mon, 5 Feb 2018 22:14:56 -0800 (PST)"
   },
   {
    "name": "Date",
    "value": "Tue, 6 Feb 2018 11:44:56 +0530"
   },
   {
    "name": "Delivered-To",
    "value": "xxx@xxx"
   },
   {
    "name": "Message-ID",
    "value": "xxx"
   },
   {
    "name": "Subject",
    "value": "TEST2"
   },
   {
    "name": "From",
    "value": "xxx"
   },
   {
    "name": "To",
    "value": "xxxx"
   },
   {
    "name": "Content-Type",
    "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=\"f403045c3c98fab46e05648518a7\""
   }
  ],
  "body": {
   "size": 0
  },
  "parts": [
   {
    "partId": "0",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\""
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 423,
     "data": "----"
    }
   }
  ]
 },
 "sizeEstimate": 1810
}
```

Some mails also have labels like [SENT, INBOX]. Is there any way to get the latest or most relevant label. I would like to categorize mails based on the labels and multiple labels create contradictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you send an email it gets the `SENT` label.  When you are trashing the email you are adding the `TRASHED` label.  It does not remove any other labels that had been added.

I would suspect that the UI version of Gmail has a filter that does not display trashed mails in the sent mail box.

Solution:  When you trash your email make sure to delete the SENT label or just filter out all other labels in your application if it has a trashed label.

The gmail api returns the data it has its up to you to either ensure that it has only the correct data by deleting other labels after you trash an email or filtering out the labels you are not interested in.

Comment: "Sent" is a system label that is automatically applied to all messages that you sent. There is no way to remove the label. (https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/eitlfDKeCso/lkXkE-cwUzkJ). So I guess UI is filtering out the trashed mail content.

Comment: I beleave that https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/delete will allow you to delete any label even system labels.   However it may have changed since i last used this method